# Error code: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, error-code

I am trying to write a code in Python and my code keeps returning a warning sign that states:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

I have included the piece of my code that this falls under:

[This is my code! I am trying to assign a value to the Month column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqSOq.png)

Comment: Post your code with your question in proper format; don't give us an image as we can't copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of pandas indexers (ix, iloc, loc) to prevent this warning. Since your indexing by location you should use iloc.

For example:

```
msft3.ix['P Values'].iloc[i] = ...
```